# is it possible to save the current state of sign() method of pdfbox? so that this content can then be used to generate digital signature and resume?

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, pdfbox

This is in continuation to a previous thread of mine. The goal is to stamp a pdf document with digital signature. For stamping I use pdfbox, for digital signature generation, there is another standalone application used.

There are 2 different servers involved.

Server A : upload pdf document -> generate a document hash -> invoke the pdfBox to stamp this document -> from sign() method of pdfbox invoke server B -> use the signature generated by server B to stamp on the document.

Server B : take the hash of the document and generate the digital signature -> return this signature to server A

The above method works completely fine, as a synchronous call flow right from document upload on server A to digital signature generation on server B and back to stamping the doc on serverA with the signature.

Now, the problem is, response from server B is asynchronous. I don't want to wait in sign() method till server B returns with the signature for me to continue and stamp the document. And if I invoke the entire flow of pdfbox again, the content in the sign() method differs everytime its called.

So is it possible to store the current state of execution, which is up until the overriden sign() method of pdfbox is invoked ? so that I can take the content in this method and call server B to generate digital signature, and when server B returns with the signature asynchronously, I can resume the working of sign() method by setting this digital signature and proceeding to stamp it on the doc?

https://github.com/johnskim9414/signPdf/blob/6d8cebe57e9b5fed2e3cc62649ecf4cd3a9e8049/src/main/java/com/sign/pdf/CustomSignature.java

or is there any method available in pdfbox where I can overwrite the content that gets generated and passed to the sign() method, by the previously generated content?

Comment: The CreateVisualSignature example has a "lateExternalSigning" feature, maybe that is what you mean.